# Is there a way to find the devices my SSD was plugged in?

Tags: windows, physical-access, ssd, snooping, hard-drive

I gave my laptop for repair to a technician now I suspect he might have copied my files to another pc by probably plugging in my SSD to other devices. I already tried checking the properties but idk why my access time is getting set to the current time of the device so I cant find out through it, Is there any way to find this ?
Do recent files also get updated even if someone uses my SSD in  their PC cause my recent files have not been altered ?

Comment: 1. no, it's just a last time snapshot, not a log. 2. no, recents are stored centrally elsewhere not on the files, and files themselves can be copied myriad ways w/o changing date atrribs.